# Use setattr in the Locust class

Tags: python, locust

I'm using Locust to load test an API. As an example, I am sending a GET request to google. My USE CASE is that I want to create the @task methods using setattr by assigning the functions dynamically to the class. This is my code

```
from locust import TaskSet, HttpUser, between, task

@task
def default_method(self):
    self.client.get("/")

class WebsiteTasks(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        print("start process")
        setattr(self, 'index', default_method)

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    host = "https://www.google.com"
    tasks = [WebsiteTasks]
    wait_time = between(1, 10)
```

As response I has that exception when start new load test browser:

`Exception: No tasks defined. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding tasks in on_start is too late, as Locust will check for the existence of tasks before actually starting (and I think this is the correct behaviour, or people might end up running on_start only to have the test fail immediately after)

Is anything stopping you from using a list, like in this example from the documentation:

```
def my_task(user):
    pass

class MyUser(User):
    tasks = [my_task]
    ...
```

You can still manipulate that list from on_start, as long as it is not empty to start with.

Comment: Yes, it can be modified afterward. I have flows where I do that. Just had to have at least one task to start with but then you can manually edit tasks on the fly. I don't use setattr for that, I directly manipulate the tasks list.